# How to set different positions for multiple elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS class:

```css
.something{
//all my css stuff here
}
```

I have 10 different elements that use this class:

```html
<div class='something'></div>
<div class='something'></div>
<div class='something'></div>
<div class='something'></div>
<div class='something'></div> //ect ect....
```

Each of those divs need to be positioned differently and I don't want to make like 10 copy's of `.something` and point each one at a different class because its only the position that needs to change.

Also, I'm using JQuery to animate these divs, like:

```js
$('.something').animate();
```

But that will animate all the divs attached to that class right? Is there any way around that?

Comment: "Bare with me"...well ok, if it helps... <removes clothes>

Comment: haha you know what I meant...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify an ID as well. So, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="something" id="s1"></div>
<div class="something" id="s2"></div>
```

Then:

```
$('#s1').animate({ ... }, speed); // animation of element 1
$('#s2').animate({ ... }, speed); // different animation of element 2
```

And still apply styles like:

```
.something {
    /* css */
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can not use IDs and simply loop: *edited for simplicity*

```
$('.something').animate({"top": "+=100px"}, speed);
```

If you'll be animating each `div` in *somewhat* the same way.

Comment: I was about to answer with an identical response.

Comment: Just for the record, multiple classes are also allowed: `<div class="something else">`

Comment: or you can just do `$(".something").animate({"top": "+=300px"}, 300);` without the each... oh and you have missed to specify a speed on your animate method

Comment: AWSOME, so in the CSS i could just do .something#s1{top:1px;},.something#s2{top:1px;} ect ect?

Comment: @nav yes or you could use more then one class

Comment: You can just do `#s1` and `#s2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use each to reference every object one at a time.

```
$('.classname').each(function(){ });
```

Comment: Can you combine `.each()` with a counter? How would you differentiate between each `<div>`?

Comment: Well, you can use $(this) from inside the function, and if you want to count the divs you just declare a variable and put varName++; in the function body

Comment: Exactly! For example, if you say $('.classname').each(function(){ $(this).addClass('newClassName'); }); This will add a new class to every object. If you need more info about any jquery function just go to api.jquery.com it's a great resource and I use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Add `id`s to your `<div>`s:

```html
<div class="something" id="one"></div>
<div class="something" id="two"></div>
```

Move your positioning CSS out of `.something` and into:

```css
#one {
    left: 20px;
}

#two {
    left: 40px;
}
```

Animate using the selector:

```js
$( '#one' ).animate();
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if i got you right. But you can also increase the value with animate.

```
$('.something').animate({"top": "+=100px"},300);
```

This is gonna ad 100px to the top of every Dom element that has the class "something"